# Method returning value depending of collection item type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

The code below add some object in `MemoryCache`. These objects can have different type.

I'd like a method able to return the object from `MemoryCache` but the return type can be different.

In my sample it's 2 but can be much more. In my sample, the type return are `IT1` or `List<IT2>`

How can I implement this method ?

I'd like method like this (the type returned can be different depending the key) :

```
public ??? GetObjectFromKey(string key)
{
    return _cache.Get(key);
}
```

Thanks,

```
MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

var it1 = new T1 { Name = "My" };
var it2 = new List<IT2>().Add(new T2 { Age = 5 });

_cache.Add("ITC1", it1, new CacheItemPolicy());
_cache.Add("ITC2", it2, new CacheItemPolicy());

var typeName = _cache.Get("ITC1").GetType();

public interface IT1
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class T1 : IT1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class T2 : IT2
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public interface IT2
{
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you could use reflection with generics to call a get method with the correct type parameter, but how would this be better than returning object. At compile time you won't know the type (because you don't know the type!) and you can find it out using GetType if you just return an object,

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your cache has to be either `object` or `dynamic`. You have no other possibility, because the classes you put into your cache have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type when you are calling the GetObjectFromKey you can use generics:

```
public T GetObjectFromKey(string key)
{
    object returnObj = _cache.Get(key);
    if(returnObj.GetType() == typeof(T)) // may need to also check for inheritance
    {
         return (T) returnObj;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new Expcetion("InvalidType");
    }
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
IT1 myObj = GetObjectFromKey<IT1>("mykey");
```

As promised, here is how you can construct the generic method from an arbitrary type at run time (though I don't see how this is going to help!):

```
Type t = typeof(Something); // your type at run time
Type cacheType = _cache.GetType(); // The type that has the GetObjectFromKeyMethod

MethodInfo lGenericMethod = cacheType.GetMethod("GetObjectFromKey");
MethodInfo lTypedMethod = lMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t);

dynamic lReturn = lTypedMethod.Invoke(_cache, new object[] { "mykey" } );
```

Though clearly you can't do anything with `lReturn` as you don't know the type at compile time and you could have just returned an object (or else some common interface) and called `GetType` on that. Still, it is fun to write fun reflection methods like that :P

Comment: Of course but I excpeted find a way withtout provide the type, but it's may be not possible.

Comment: OK well then you can use reflection to get the type and construct the method at runtime (I'll add that later, away from a compiler at the moment!), but I refer you to my earlier comment, if you aren't using the type at compile time, why not just return a object?

Comment: Added that, though not sure how it'll help. What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Generics?

```
public T GetObjectFromKey<T>(string key)
{
    return (T)_cache.Get(key);
}
```

Comment: Of course but I expected find a way withtout provide the type, but it's may be not possible.

Comment: If don't know the type at compile-time, it won't work because the Get method returns object.